# Double cone intersecting plane

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to reproduce the following picture of a double cone intersecting a plane but fail miserably when it comes to drawing the cones with the proper opacity level.
[image: double cone]

This is how far I got:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \draw[->] (-3,0)--(3,0); \node[below] at (3,0) {$x_2$};
    \draw[->] (0,-1)--(0,2.5); \node[right] at (0,2.5) {$x_0$};
    \draw[<-] (-1.5,-.6)--(1.5,.6); \node[below] at (-1.5,-.8) {$x_1$};
    \fill[gray!20,opacity=.7] (-4.5,.2)--(-1.5,1.4)--(4.5,1.4)--(1.5,.2)--cycle;
    \draw (0,1.4)--(0,.8);
    \fill[gray,opacity=.2] (-3,0) ellipse (0.6cm and 1.6cm);
    \fill[gray,opacity=.2] (3,0) ellipse (.6cm and 1.6cm);
    \fill[gray,opacity=.5] (-3,-1.6)--(0,0)--(-3,1.6) arc (90:270:.6cm and 1.6cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The main point where I fail is when tracing out the path from the lower point of the ellipse to the origin to the upper point of the ellipse and then back along the inner arc (rather than along the outer one which is presently the case).

I don't need it to be rotated ("around x_0") like in the picture above and shaded in a fancy way, I just want to get the opacities right so that my picture makes some sense.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is a recycled old drawing of mine. It's not exactly the same but I think that it could be helpful. You can rotate it or change the axes and add the labels.

The trick here is drawing the hyperbola inside the plane with the `canvas is yz plane...` option from tikz 3d library. Then we need to look at the order of the different parts for a correct visibility. Unfortunately we need 'a couple' of math computations and changes of variables for finding the tangent generatrices and the tangent points in the ellipses.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

% isometric axes
\pgfmathsetmacro\xx{1/sqrt(2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xy{1/sqrt(6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zz{sqrt(2/3)}

% dimensions and some maths
\def\ch{2}   % cone height
\def\cr{1}   % cone radius \cr < \ch
\def\px{1.5} % plane semi-width \px > \cr
\def\py{0.5} % plane distance to z-axis \py < \cr
\pgfmathsetmacro\ca{atan(\cr/\ch)}                         % cone angle
\pgfmathsetmacro\cg{sqrt(\ch*\ch+\cr*\cr}                  % cone generatrix
\pgfmathsetmacro\gs{sqrt((2*\ch*\ch-\cr*\cr)/(3*\cr*\cr))} % generatrix slope
\pgfmathsetmacro\xt{sqrt(6)*\gs*\ch/(1+3*\gs*\gs)}         % tangent point x
\pgfmathsetmacro\yt{\gs*\xt}                               % tangent point y
\pgfmathsetmacro\aa{(\ch*\zz-\yt)/\xy/2-\xt/\xx/2}         % coordinate x in xy plane
\pgfmathsetmacro\bb{(\ch*\zz-\yt)/\xy/2+\xt/\xx/2}         % coordinate y in xy plane
\pgfmathsetmacro\at{atan(\bb/\aa)+180}                     % angle to the tangent point
\pgfmathsetmacro\ix{sqrt(\cr*\cr-\py*\py)}                 % intersection plane-cone x
\pgfmathsetmacro\hv{\ch*\py/\cr}                           % hyperbola vertex

% styles
\tikzset%
{%
  cone  back/.style={red,left color=white,right color=red!50!black,fill opacity=0.8},
  cone front/.style={red,left color=red, fill opacity=0.5},
       plane/.style={blue,fill=blue!20,fill opacity=0.75} 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,%
                    x={(-\xx cm,-\xy cm)},y={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},z={(0cm,\zz cm)}]
  % cone, top base
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=\ch]
    \coordinate (TLT) at (90-\at:\cr);  % tangent point, left
    \coordinate (TRT) at (\at:\cr);     % tangent point, right
    \draw[cone back] (0,0) circle (\cr);
  \end{scope}
  % plane and hyperbola
  \begin{scope}[rotate around z=-30,canvas is xz plane at y=\py,]
    \draw[plane] plot[domain=-\ix:\ix,samples=21,smooth] (\x,{-\ch/\cr*sqrt(\x*\x+\py*\py)}) -- cycle;
    \draw[plane] plot[domain=\ix:-\ix,samples=21,smooth] (\x,{ \ch/\cr*sqrt(\x*\x+\py*\py)}) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
  % cone, bottom base
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=-\ch]
    \coordinate (TLB) at (180+\at:\cr); % tangent point, left
    \coordinate (TRB) at (270-\at:\cr); % tangent point, right
    \draw[red] (0,0) circle (\cr);
  \end{scope}
  % cone, surface
  \draw[cone front]
    {[canvas is xy plane at z= \ch] (TLT) arc (90-\at:\at:\cr)} -- (TLB)
    {[canvas is xy plane at z=-\ch] arc (180+\at:-90-\at:\cr)} -- cycle;
  % plane and hyperbola revisited
  \begin{scope}[rotate around z=-30,canvas is xz plane at y=\py,]
    \draw[plane] (-\px,-\ch) -- (-\ix,-\ch) -- plot[domain=-\ix:\ix,samples=21,smooth] (\x,{-\ch/\cr*sqrt(\x*\x+\py*\py)}) -|
                  (\px,\ch)  -- (\ix,\ch)   -- plot[domain=\ix:-\ix,samples=21,smooth] (\x,{ \ch/\cr*sqrt(\x*\x+\py*\py)}) -| cycle;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]